# text with no wrap next to icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an accordion made up code like so

```
<label for='product-45-45' class="active">
 <input type='checkbox' class='regular-checkbox big-checkbox ' checked='checked' id='product-45-45'
                       name='product_id_page-0[45-45]' value='45-45' data-first_price="11.99" data-second_price=""
                       data-paysys=""/>
                <span class="accord-text">
                    <strong>Bundle Pack:</strong> Practise every type of test</br><em>£35 for 1 year's access -
                        <strong>BEST OFFER!</strong></em>
            </span>
            </label>
```

style

```
.accord-text {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 182px;
    margin-top: 3px;
}
```

I floated the span right then margin right and top to position the text, this works fine on chrome but not Firefox. What is the best way of constructing the code and styling so that I get the desired effect (like the screen shot) that is cross browser compatible?
[image]

Comment: I recommend looking into CSS Flexbox.  It'll change your life.  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: thanks, may be helpful. getting fed up with perfecting designs then finding Firefox problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed

```
 <label for='product-45-45' class="active">
               <input type="checkbox" style="float: left;" class="regular-checkbox big-checkbox " checked="checked" id="product-45-45" name="product_id_page-0[45-45]" value="45-45" data-first_price="11.99" data-second_price="" data-paysys="">

                <div class="accord-text">
                    <strong>Bundle Pack:</strong> Practise every type of test</br><em>£35 for 1 year's access -
                        <strong>BEST OFFER!</strong></em>
            </div>
            </label>
```

and

```
.accord-text {
        /*float: left;*/
        /*margin-right: 182px;*/
        margin-left: 30px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would reduce the `margin-right` value in `.accord-text` Since you use a `<br>` anyway, you don't really need it, but it might cause additional line-wrapping when there is less space.